# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I've this error when I use my application :

```
05-01 14:18:41.000: E/AndroidRuntime(26607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 14:18:41.000: E/AndroidRuntime(26607): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

The method with the issue :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int postion,
        long index) {

    // Get MAC adress matching the last 17 characters of the TextView
   String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();    //  HERE IS THE ISSUE
   String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);


    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) view.getTag();

    showEquipementActivity(device);
}
```

And the XML File :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_tactea"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tactea"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/label_list_of_devices"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_scan" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDevices"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This XML file is to display paired bluetooth devices and news devices found.

Can you help me ?

How to change those lines ?

```
   String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();    //  HERE IS THE ISSUE
   String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
```

Update: I get following error:

```
05-01 14:39:33.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-01 14:39:33.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7160): java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-01 14:39:33.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7160): at com.example.cajou.DiscoverDevicesActivity.onItemClick(DiscoverDevicesActivity.ja‌​va:179) 
05-01 14:39:33.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7160): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301) 
05-01 14:39:33.150: E/AndroidRuntime(7160): at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1276)
```

UPDATE 2 :

I've tried :

```
TextView textview=(TextView) ((LinearLayout)view).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String info = textview.getText().toString();
```

But I've an issue with this line :

```
String info = textview.getText().toString();
```

UPDATE 3 :

I've tried :

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final String info = tv.getText().toString();
```

But same issue... 
This line is the issue :

```
final String info = tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: how are you filling up the ListView? Have you your custom adapter?

Comment: Post your custom listrow xml file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use only

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String info = textview.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 TextView textview=((LinearLayout)view).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 String info = textView.getText().toString();
```

The xml layout file you have provided is not needed here. The list view row file is culprit .so use Id of Textview that is mentioned in row.xml .

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) But I have always the problem.
I put:TextView textview=(TextView) ((LinearLayout)view).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 String info = textview.getText().toString(); 
THE ERROR IS :
05-01 14:47:07.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 14:47:07.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16615): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 14:47:07.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16615): at com.example.cajou.DiscoverDevicesActivity.onItemClick(DiscoverDevicesActivity.java:179)
05-01 14:47:07.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16615):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)

Comment: I understand, but where is this XML file ?

Comment: Now you got Null pointer this may be due to wrong id kindly share your row.xml file for list view. You have created a layout for displaying data in list view that file is known as row.xml file. You also passed this as a parameter in your adapter while intializing that.

Comment: Exactly ! :)  So it's necessary to change the id ?

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` returns an `EditableText`, not a `String`. You have to use the `toString()` method to cast it into a `String` type:

```
String text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When the same id is used for different components, this error occurs.