# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, exception

Before posting this question I already looked [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318144/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-linearlayout-cannot-be-cast-to-andr) and [Android java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951847/android-java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-relativelayout-cannot-be-ca), but I can't find any help from those 2 questions.

I got this exception-

```
09-14 11:57:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(8135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstpage/com.example.firstpage.CreateGroup}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
09-14 11:57:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.example.firstpage.CreateGroup.onCreate(CreateGroup.java:43)
```

The part of code shown when clicked on " 09-14 11:57:57.813: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):    at com.example.firstpage.CreateGroup.onCreate(CreateGroup.java:43) " is-

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_group);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextcg1);  // CreateGroup.java:43
```

The XML file of particular portion is-

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/DimGray"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextcg1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Group Name" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
```

Why I got this exception and how can it be corrected ?

---

UPDATE :

As said by Falmarri and Ted Hopp, I cleaned my project and now its working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Clean your project. Also if that's your whole xml file then you're missing the closing of your linear layouts.

Comment: @Falmarri Thats not the whole XML file.

Comment: Definitely clean your project. Also, if you have qualified resource directories (layout-[something]), be sure that the layout being loaded is the one you think. It wouldn't hurt to run Android lint as well to check for other possible errors (e.g., the same id being used twice in the same file).

Comment: sometimes closing ecllipse and reopening again solves this error. While changing xml files at some time R.java stops generating causing the exception